# Reading configuration file from deployed application with wsadmin scripting

Tags: file, scripting, websphere-8, wsadmin

Is it possible to read an arbitrary file from a deployed application through `wsadmin` scripting of WebSphere 8.5?

I need this for a scenario reading specific configured parameter of a file in this application to figure out how all my applications on the server are running.

I'm using WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.